# Reveal all cards when hovered on a card and stack cards on mouseout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write HTML and CSS (no JS yet), where in if I mouse over on stacked cards, they roll up to show all cards.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/vpdevbox/pen/MWbGbjo)

**Initial state:**

[image: Stacked Cards]

**Desired State: Cards stack up on top of each other when mouse over on any card.**

[image: Cards Revealed.]

I have created a CSS class called `stack`. If I attach it to `card` element, Ex: `<div class="card stack">` it shows the desired stack behavior.

If I add a hover action to the card, the animation is jittery and doesn't work properly. ex:

```
.card:hover {
  transform: translateY(calc((var(--y) * -105% + 50px)));
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

How do I fix it, so it rolls up the cards when hovered on the cards, but when mouseout of the cards, it should show stacked view again.

Here's the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #e8eaed;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 500px;
  right: 100px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #00000080;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 #00000040, 0 5px 5px 0#00000020;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  padding:15px;
}

.card {
  transform: translateY(calc((var(--y) * 20px) - 50%)) scale(calc(1.0 + var(--y) * 0.05));
}

.card-avatar {
  display:block;
}
.card-avatar img {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  float:left;
}
.card-title {
  font-size:16px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.card-header {
  height:30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.card-body {
  margin-top:-30px;
}

.stack {
  transform: translateY(calc((var(--y) * -105% + 200px)));
  box-shadow:none;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: translateY(calc((var(--y) * -105% + 50px)));
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="--y:1">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-avatar">
      <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/363633-200.png">
    </div>
    <div class="card-title">Announcement 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    This is announcement 1.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card" style="--y:2">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-avatar">
      <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/363633-200.png">
    </div>
    <div class="card-title">Announcement 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    This is announcement 2.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its better to capsulate the cards in one div and perform the hover on the capsulated div `.card-stack`

```css
body {
  background-color: #e8eaed;
}

.card-stack {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #00000080;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 #00000040, 0 5px 5px 0#00000020;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  padding: 15px;
}

.card {
  transform: translateY(calc((var(--y) * 20px) - 50%)) scale(calc(1.0 + var(--y) * 0.05));
}

.card-avatar {
  display: block;
}

.card-avatar img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.card-header {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card-body {
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.stack {
  transform: translateY(calc((var(--y) * -105% + 200px)));
  box-shadow: none;
}

.card-stack:hover .card {
  transform: translateY(calc((var(--y) * -105% + 50px)));
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-stack">
  <div class="card" style="--y:1">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-avatar">
        <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/363633-200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-title">Announcement 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      This is announcement 1.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="--y:2">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-avatar">
        <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/363633-200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-title">Announcement 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      This is announcement 2.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```